# Converting a python dataframe from AWS lambda to CSV in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to convert a write a python Dataframe and store it in S3. I have added the required layers in Lambda (s3fs & fsspec) and have provided requisite permissions to lambda to write to s3. But not I am getting the below error:

"errorMessage": "module 's3fs' has no attribute 'S3FileSystem'"

Below are the relevant lines of my code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
df.to_csv('s3://buckets/<my-bukcet-name>/mydata.csv')
```

Any pointers on what could be the reason for this?

Regards,
Dbeings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of including those layers, I would recommend including the Amazon provided [AWS Data Wrangler layer](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/336392948345/aws-data-wrangler-layer-py3-9).

Then you would use [AWS Data Wrangler](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/003%20-%20Amazon%20S3.html#1.1-Writing-CSV-files) to write your dataframe directly to S3, like the following:

```
import awswrangler as wr

wr.s3.to_csv(df, 's3://buckets/<my-bukcet-name>/mydata.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, using wrangler for writing fixed it! The below code worked.

wr.s3.to_csv(df, 's3://<my-bukcet-name>/mydata.csv', index=False)

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it fixed your problem. Thanks.

Comment: This library is must-have for anyone extracting data and dumping it somewhere in AWS